# Альтернатива imagejpeg

Tags: php, jpeg

В фотошопе есть опция "сохранить для web". Через нее можно сохранить картинку в очень хорошем качестве, а средствами php такого добиться не получается. Такое ощущение, что фотошоп обрабатывает одну картинку частями, там где тест качество лучше.

Есть какая-нибудь библиотека, которая может сохранить картинку в качестве сравнимом с фотошоп?

Comment: а что вы с ним делаете? на [Stack overflow][1] есть похожее...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076716/php-imagejpeg-quality-stinks-why

Comment: с кем с ним? качество говорю плохое. попробуй сохранить с помощью imagejpeg картинку с красным текстом мелким тонким шрифтом на черном фоне.

Answer (score 2):

Советую [использовать imagemagick](http://highload.com.ua/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83+%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E+imagemagick+%D0%B8+PHP%3F) (его можно очень хорошо настроить) и [инструменты оптимизации картинок](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2010/07/02/optimizaciya-kartinok/) в дополнение к ресайзеру. Либо только последние.

Answer (score 0):

Эм...

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

Третий параметр кагбэ намекает.

Еще могу предложить погуглить и поюзать [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: мазафака, говорю же это не оно! Хоть на 100 его выкрути, если у тебя скажем картинка красный текст на черном фоне - качество будет плохое.
Если ее сохранить в фотошопе - все будет нормально видно.

про ImageMagick почитаю.